# Каким регулярным выражением можно воспользоваться для валидации имени пользователя?(username) | Python

Tags: python, re

передо мной встала задача отвалидировать введенное пользователем значение(имя пользователя).
Необходимо, чтобы оно соответствовало требованиям

- Имя пользователя может содержать буквы латинского алфавита (a–z), цифры (0–9).
- Запрещено использовать амперсанд (&), собаку(@), знаки равенства (=) и сложения (+), скобки (<>), запятую (,), символ подчеркивания (_), апостроф ('), дефис (-) и точки.

Эти требования взяты из Gmail, но слегка откорректированы под проект.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с регуляркой. В регулярных выражениях я вообще 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение можно упростить с помощью флага `re.I`, который позволяет искать строки, не обращая внимания на регистр:

```
import re
valid_pattern = re.compile(r"^[a-z0-9]+$", re.I)

def validate(name: str) -> bool:
    return bool(valid_pattern.match(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

text = 'test@/+test'

pattern = re.compile('[+,@]')
res = pattern.findall(text)

if res:
    print("Нельзя!!!")
else:
    print("Зя!!!")
```

но можно обойтись и без них в таком легком запросе:

```
text = 'test@/+test'

seq = '+@'

res = any([text.find(letter) != -1 for letter in seq])

if res:
    print("Нельзя!!!")
else:
    print("Зя!!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def validate(name: str)->bool:
    if re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", name):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(validate("Am9h31d0jn"))
print(validate("12"))
print(validate("john@doe"))
```

```
True
True
False
```